# Hide specific elements onload or ready or page:change if select tags have specific value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide some elements when a page is loaded.

Currently I'm using `'page:change'` because I'm working in Ruby on Rails with Turbolinks.

If the div contains a select tag with a specific value, I want to hide some elements.
The page can contain multiple of those select tags, so I can't use ID's.

Code here does not work:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(){

    if ($('.q_type_select').val() == 'text' || $('.q_type_select').val() == 'area') {
            $(this).closest('.question_fieldset').children('.choice_fieldset').hide();
            $(this).closest('.question_fieldset').children('.add_fields').hide();
        };
};
```

**I guess that `$(this)` only works if you click?**

If I do this:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(){

    if ($('.q_type_select').val() == 'text' || $('.q_type_select').val() == 'area') {
            $('.question_fieldset').children('.choice_fieldset').hide();
            $('.question_fieldset').children('.add_fields').hide();
        };
};
```

I get all of the elements that have that class to hide and not the ones I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: just use $(document).ready

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Comment: How does that suppose to answer the question? I'm not asking that, please read the question.

Comment: Is `.on('page:change',` pseudo-code? I've never seen that before. Please post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: In the first example you have not selected anything so `this` is meaningless. If you give an example of your HTML I could give you a `$('selector').each()` that would probably work.

Comment: @dlsso select tags have a class `q_type_select`. Their parent's `div` class is `question_fieldset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming whatever you have there is correct (since there is no HTML to look to). 
Try this

```
$(function(){
   $('.q_type_select').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.val() == 'text' || $this.val() == 'area') {
        $this.closest('.question_fieldset').children('.choice_fieldset').hide();
        $this.closest('.question_fieldset').children('.add_fields').hide();

    };
  })
});
```

Loop through all of the element (`.q_type_select`) present in the page on document ready function and hide() it

Comment: Works just as I expected. Thank you very much. Didn't know there was an `each` method here, nice.

Comment: Sniped again, haha.

Comment: @disso :):)  you mentioned about `.each` earlier though.. :) :)